# Export as Snippet menu option missing from Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

I found [these wonderful instructions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/226359/Creating-Our-Own-Snippets-Using-Visual-Studio) on how to create your own code snippets in Visual Studio (after using them in Xcode, I have become addicted to snippets).  However, when I go to follow the first steps, I select my snippet body code, and right-click, there is no menu pick to export the snippet!  And, a bit of Googling failed to turn up any results (as in 0 results, odd).  Does anyone know how to enable the menu pick?

Also, I went into Tools / Options, checked off "Show all settings" - and I was unable to find any relevant option that may enable snippet management.

When I go to the Snippet Manager, apparently it is expecting to already have a Snippet XML file to add, and won't give me some dialog to build my own new snippet.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, although it dances around the subject, it mentions that you must have Snippet Designer, but no info on how to install it or where to get it!  You can obtain it from the GitHub repository at https://github.com/mmanela/snippetdesigner

Comment: yes, w/o snippet designer extension you cant export code as a snippet.